# NEST Search not found any result

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Just find out about nest. I already insert some number of document in Elastic Search. Right now I want to search the data based on my type, subcriberId. I did run through curl and it works just fine. But when I tried using nest, no result found.

My curl which work:

http://localhost:9200/20160902/_search?q=subscribeId:aca0ca1a-c96a-4534-ab0e-f844b81499b7

My NEST code:

```
        var local = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(local);
        var elastic = new ElasticClient(settings);

        var response = elastic.Search<IntegrationLog>(s => s
                            .Index(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))
                            .Type("integrationlog")
                            .Query(q => q
                                .Term(p => p.SubscribeId, new Guid("aca0ca1a-c96a-4534-ab0e-f844b81499b7"))
                            )
                        );
```

Can someone point what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key difference between your curl request and your NEST query is that the former is using a [`query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) query and the latter, a [`term`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) query. A `query_string` query input undergoes analysis at query time whilst a `term` query input does not so depending on how `subscribeId` is analyzed (or not), you may see different results. Additionally, your curl request is searching across all document types within the index `20160902`.

To perform the exact same query in NEST as your curl request would be

```
void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        // set up NEST with the convention to use the type name
        // "integrationlog" for the IntegrationLog
        // POCO type
        .InferMappingFor<IntegrationLog>(m => m
            .TypeName("integrationlog")
        );

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    var searchResponse = client.Search<IntegrationLog>(s => s
        .Index("20160902")
        // search across all types. Note that documents found
        // will be deserialized into instances of the 
        // IntegrationLog type
        .AllTypes()
        .Query(q => q
            // use query_string query
            .QueryString(qs => qs
                .Fields(f => f
                    .Field(ff => ff.SubscribeId)
                )
                .Query("aca0ca1a-c96a-4534-ab0e-f844b81499b7")
            )
        )
    );
}

public class IntegrationLog
{
    public Guid SubscribeId { get; set; }
}
```

This yields

```
POST http://localhost:9200/20160902/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "aca0ca1a-c96a-4534-ab0e-f844b81499b7",
      "fields": [
        "subscribeId"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

this specifies the `query_string` query in the body of the request which is  analogous to using the `q` query string parameter to specify the query.

Comment: Thanks! Just realise there is difference.